# Using anchor tags in conjunction with a form's action attribute

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm building a CMS for a site with php. I have multiple forms on a page which posts to itself. Every time the page reloads to populate the forms, it displays the top of the page. (like normal) The pseudocode  below may illustrate my question better:

```
<Form 1>(top of page)
   bla
   bla
   bla
</form1>
<Form 2>(middle of page)
   bla
   bla
   bla
</form2>
<Form 3>(bottom of page) (how do i get this to show at the top when the page reloads?)
   bla
   bla
   bla
</form3>
```

I feel like theres an easy way im not seeing. But its late and its been that kind of day. Thanks in advance to everyone as usual.

Comment: You want to scroll to form element, or you want to shuffle it to the top?

Comment: I just want to scroll to it like the effect of a normal html anchor tag. But can i do that with using a form with something like this?

Comment: <form action = 'this_page.php'>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can insert an element with `id="idname"` before each form, then include that anchor (`#idname`) in the form action.

```
<div id="form1"></div>
<form action="this_page.php#form1">
...
</form>

<div id="form2"></div>
<form action="this_page.php#form2">
...
</form>
```

What happens: after form submission, the anchor will be respected scrolling the page to the element with that ID.

Note that, having an empty element just before the form allows to scroll the screen exactly to that point, so, to scroll just before the start of the form.

Comment: In HTML5, the name attribute is not supported.  Instead,  use the id attribute.

Comment: You can also put the `id` attribute right on the form; no need for the superfluous `a`

Comment: I tried to edit the answer with @Minja's suggestion (+4 upvotes); and describing why using an empty element before the form could have sense, since this clarification was requested by Explosion_Pills (+4 upvotes as well).

Comment: Holy smokes, @ValerioBozz you responded to a comment I gave a decade ago while still in college myself.  Way to make me feel old!!  :D

Comment: Way to make you feel very useful in the world, even after a decade @Minja! :D

Answer (score 5):

It's a well-kept secret that you can use the fragment (`#` part of a URL) to scroll to *any* element on a page, not just `a`nchors.  However, this is done with the `id` attribute rather than `name`.  For example.

```
<form id="form_1" ...>
...
<form id="form_3" ...>
```

PHP:

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '#form_3');
```

Comment: ok cool thx. My only question now is where do i put that php? Since i have multiple forms do i grab the id of the used form and tell your php which form it is with a variable? (Im confusing myself.) Im a newbee but getting better

Comment: @NickG77 you sound like you have the semblance of the solution in your mind.  I think you can definitely work it out.  Just try some things out and if it doesn't work, come back with more specific questions.